# No such shell function 'self-insert' using Oh My Posh

Tags: command-line, zsh

I'm using [Oh My Posh](https://ohmyposh.dev/) on my `zsh` terminal (GNOME Terminal). However, every time I type on the terminal, `No such shell function 'self-insert'` appears on the prompt after the first character is typed.